# How to create this schema like model in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to create a schema output using the c# model.
Example Schema

```
Food:[["burger", "french fries", "nuggets"], "status": "delivered"]
```

Model:

```
Public class Food
{
public List<item> items {get; set;}
}

public class item
{
public List<string> food_item {get; set;}

public string status {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid json. An array can't have a property. An object would be valid though; `Food: { "food_item" : [...], "status": "delivered"}`

Comment: Your JSON looks incomplete - can you please verify your JSON?

Answer (score 1):

The proper json should look like below

```
"Food":[{"food_item":["burger", "french fries", "nuggets"], "status": "delivered"}]
```

And the model (use https://json2csharp.com/ to validate and convert your json to model)

```
public class Food
{
    public List<string> food_item { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Food> Food { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize using below code

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

Comment: I am not trying to make it proper json. The output format is supposed to look like that. Anyway thanks